# how to recived the GridTemplate column value in RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

I want to fetch a grid template column value in the textbox?
for Sample :
GridDarkhast.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex]["TemplateColumn"].Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the control within your ItemTemplate. Example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="asdf" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

---

```
GridDarkhast.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex]["TemplateColumn"].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox...
```

In fact, you can ignore the column and use FindControl on the row itself because the first naming container is the row (GridItem). So your code may look like this:

```
TextBox tb = 
GridDarkhast.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
```

There are another ways, but judging by your code this would be the best one for you.

Good luck, 
Daniel